# Does inflation equal more loans?

Tags: banking, loans, inflation

I am wondering if the banks are favored by high inflation levels? Do higher inflation levels equal more loans? I am looking for another way of looking at the problems of inflation and not just from a supply/demand perspective.

Answer (score 2):

"[What is the relationship between inflation and interest rates?](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/12/inflation-interest-rate-relationship.asp)" notes a relationship between inflation and interest rates that would suggest high inflation would imply higher interest rates that would mean less loans as money becomes more expensive in a sense. In contrast, in times of low inflation then rates may be low and thus there is a greater chance of people and businesses wanting loans.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of operations, banks are indifferent to inflation.

Short rates except right before a recession or near-recession are always lower than long rates, regardless of inflation level, assuming no quotas or price controls.

Banks produce credit by borrowing short to lend long, so as long as short rates are lower than long rates, they can be expected to produce loans, again assuming no quotas or price controls.

In short, from the banks' perspective, inflation does not affect their desire to produce credit.